# Action Script 3: Calling String variable as function

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a function,

```
function tempFeedBack():void
    {
        trace("called");
    }
```

and event listener works perfect when I write function name directly like this,

```
thumbClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tempFeedBack);
```

But, when I give the function name as string like this,

```
thumbClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this["tempFeedBack"]());
```

It is not working! It says, `TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got that error because simply `this["tempFeedBack"]()` is not a `Function` object, which is the `listener` parameter of the `addEventListener()` function, in addition, it's nothing because your `tempFeedBack()` function cannot return any value.

To more understand that, what you have wrote is equivalent to :

```
thumbClip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tempFeedBack());
```

Here you can see that you have passed the returned value of your `tempFeedBack()` function as the `listener` parameter which should be a `Function` object, but your `tempFeedBack()` can return nothing !

So, just to explain more, if you want that what you have wrote work, you should do something like this :

```
function tempFeedBack():Function 
{
    return function():void { 
            trace("called");
        }
}
```

But I think that what you meant is :

```
// dont forget to set a MouseEvent param here
function tempFeedBack(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    trace("called");
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this["tempFeedBack"]);
// you can also write it 
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.tempFeedBack);
```

Hope that can help.